How to discretize a label
I have some labels which tells the differences between the predictions and the truth. If the differences are small, then it will be labelled as xDiff and otherwise, labelled as Diff.
However, it is actually hard to know how small is considered as small, which is the threshold.
Is there a way to guide this?
I am thinking to treat the threshold as one of the hyperparameter and was thinking to select the threshold that gives the best performance on validation set, I am not too sure whether this is valid though
